# How to add music in the background in the Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

When my app is running I want to be able to play music. How can I do that?

Comment: Did you check this on google? Check http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Background-Audio-in-WinRT-344bcf4d

Answer (score 0):

Follow given link:

[Background Audio Player Demo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202978%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)